# Why is the Return statement in my Switch statement not working as expected?

Tags: javascript

```
const customer = [10, 10]; // input array

const lemonadeChange = function (bills) {  

let five = 0, ten = 0;

bills.forEach((ele, idx) => {

switch (ele) {
  case 5:
    five += 1;
    break;

  case 10:
    if (five === 0) {
      return false; //at this point the function should stop. Instead it proceeds. 
    }
    else {
      five -= 1;
      ten += 1;
    }

  case 20:
    if (five !== 0 && ten !== 0) {
      five -= 1, ten -= 1;
    }
    else if (five > 2) {
      five -= 3;
    }
    else {
      return false;
    }


}

})

return true; //the function should be returning false because the variable five has a value of 0;
}
```

**Input**: Integer array of size 2.
**Result**: True
**Expected Result**: False.

In the Switch case of 10, the function lemonadeChange should return false and stop execution. Instead, the function continues to loop through the array and the returns true outside the loop. I ran the code using a debugger and I still can't figure out why the return statement at case 10 isn't working. I would appreciate your help, thanks.

Comment: `(ele, idx) => { .. }` is an arrow function. And `return` _"stop"_ that function as expected. But it does not stop the `forEach` and does not exit the `function (bills) { ... }` function because the `return` does not belong to that function.

Answer (score 0):

`forEach()` will execute the enclosed function for every element in `bills`. The return statement ends the function call, which just makes `forEach()` move on to the next element.

If you don't want to run through every element, you will need to use a for loop instead of `forEach()`.